# Selenium Automation - Need to combine 1 or more xpath locators to form a single locator

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation, browser-automation

The scenario here is I need to Assert whether the status of a jobname is changed to Completed, But the issue is that on the UI page the Job status HTML element is similar for all the different job names.

Below is the sample HTML code:

```
<div class="flex-primary">
<i class="gray hwx-test test-status fa provider-logo hwx-test na na-testing " title="Completed"></i>
<span class="hwx-title" title="job1">job1</span>
</div>
<div class="flex-primary">
<i class="gray hwx-test test-status fa provider-logo hwx-test na na-testing " title="Completed"></i>
<span class="hwx-title" title="job2">job2</span>
</div>
<div class="flex-primary">
<i class="gray hwx-test test-status fa provider-logo hwx-test na na-testing " title="Completed"></i>
<span class="hwx-title" title="job3">job3</span>
</div>
```

I want a locator which will uniquely be able to point to a job title in completed state
i.e: I want a xpath or any other locator which can combine & give me 1 single output for below 2 xpath's result:

```
//span[@title='job1'] and //i[@title='Completed']
```

Comment: `//span[@title='job1'] and //i[@title='Completed']` is one XPath. Where is the second? What is your desired output?

Comment: Both are 2 different xpath's .... I want an XPath or any other locator which will give me a combined result of these 2 individual locators as one. hope I'm clear in my explanation :)

Comment: I'm afraid no :) `//span[@title='job1'] and //i[@title='Completed']` is a valid XPath (SINGLE) that checks whether two nodes exist and returns boolean. If this is not your desired output specify EXACT output you want to get

Comment: @AutomationEngr `//span[@title='job1']/..//i[@title='Completed']` - this will return `i` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below xpath will give you the div which contains jobname as `job1` and title as `completed`

```
//span[@title='job1']/preceding-sibling::i[@title='Completed']/parent::div
```

Below xpath will point to the `i` tag of jobname of `job1` which is `completed`

```
//span[@title='job1']/parent::div/i[@title='Completed']
```