# Selenium Automation - Need xpath to locate 2 UI elements with almost same properties located in different HTML tags

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation, browser-automation

The scenario here is I need to Assert whether the status of a jobname is changed to Completed, But the issue is that on the UI page the Job status HTML element*(title="Completed")* is similar for all the different job names*(title="Job1")*.

Below is the sample HTML code:

```
<div class="flex-primary"><i title="Completed" class="fa fa-cube provider-logo hwx-secondary orange"></i><span class="hwx-title" title="Job1">Job1</span> &nbsp;</div>
<span><button class="btn btn-icon btn-transparent inline-overview-actions" eventkey="1" title="Completed"><i class="fa fa-play-circle hwx-secondary inline-actions-overview no-select"></i></button></span>

<div class="flex-primary"><i title="Completed" class="fa fa-cube provider-logo hwx-secondary orange"></i><span class="hwx-title" title="Job2">Job2</span> &nbsp;</div>
<span><button class="btn btn-icon btn-transparent inline-overview-actions" eventkey="1" title="Completed"><i class="fa fa-play-circle hwx-secondary inline-actions-overview no-select"></i></button></span>

<div class="flex-primary"><i title="Completed" class="fa fa-cube provider-logo hwx-secondary orange"></i><span class="hwx-title" title="Job3">Job3</span> &nbsp;</div>
<span><button class="btn btn-icon btn-transparent inline-overview-actions" eventkey="1" title="Completed"><i class="fa fa-play-circle hwx-secondary inline-actions-overview no-select"></i></button></span>
```

I want a locator which will uniquely be able to point to a job title in completed state i.e: I want a xpath which will be a combined output for below 2 xpath's result:

```
//span[@title='job1'] and //button[@title='Completed']
```

**NOTE: This is a follow up question for Answer received for** [Selenium Automation - Need to combine 1 or more xpath locators to form a single locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141023/selenium-automation-need-to-combine-1-or-more-xpath-locators-to-form-a-single#64141023)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uniquely identify each `button` you can find the `following::span[1]` and then find the button.

```
//span[@title='Job1']/following::span[1]/button[@title='Completed']
//span[@title='Job2']/following::span[1]/button[@title='Completed']
//span[@title='Job3']/following::span[1]/button[@title='Completed']
```